# iOS CoreLocation in background

Tags: ios, background, core-location, kill

I'm developing a location tracking app. The user can start a tracking, do whatever he wants (put the app in the background, lock the phone, etc), go back to the app and stop the tracking.

I'd like the tracking to restart if the app is killed (by the system or the user). To do so, I saw in the doc that I have to use the significant location change service, but this service does not send enough locations. Is it possible to restart the standard location service when the app is restarted thanks to the significant location change service? Or would the app be rejected?

Answer (score 0):

Following methods would wake your application up even if is killed in the background:

1. Region events
2. Visit events
3. Significant location events

Your application will be launched with location key in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Here is an example on how to handle it gracefully (from http://nshipster.com/launch-options/):

```
// .h
@import CoreLocation;

@interface AppDelegate () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

// .m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Location Services Disabled", nil)
                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.", nil)
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Also, you are not limited to using Significant location monitoring or region monitoring etc. You can use different mechanisms for different use cases. E.g. You can use region monitoring to setup a fallback region around the user and everytime an exit event happens, your application will be woken up with `location` key. You can then restart location services.